# Katalon open a link into a browser

Tags: katalon-studio

I cannot open a browser setting as starting link Google site.

Here is my code:

```
WebUI.openBrowser('http://www.google.ie')
```

but unfortunately when I run it I can see this:

1. A tab is opening in Chrome, but url contains data:, instead http://www.google.ie
2. An exception is thrown

   > Unable to open browser with url: '' (Root cause: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed

What can be the cause? And most of all, what can be the solution?

Answer (score 1):

you can try :

```
WebUI.openBrowser('')

WebUI.navigateToUrl('http://www.google.ie')
```

if any problem occurs please post it with error
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I had a old Google Chrome version (47x) and it requires at minimum Google Chrome version 62x. Updated, finally works!
Thanks.